# Scrapy how to define custom ItemExporters

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to export scraped data into the google sheets. I know I can write own pipeline to export need info, but from scrapy documentation pipelines aren't intended to use in that way.
They suggested to use Item Exporters, but it's not clear for me the usage of it:

1. Where I should define the custom exporter?
2. What kind of changes I need to do in settings.py to enable custom exporter?

Comment: pbskumar gave a quite complete solution:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290876/how-to-create-custom-scrapy-item-exporter][1]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I don't know how I missed that