# Get sublevels headings in separate lines scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code that is supposed to scrpae wikiperdia list of headings.. In the output csv, I expect to get the headings (the main headings) and in column B, the subheadings
My problem is with the subheadings as I got all the subheadings in one line and I need to put each subheading in one row
Here's my try (but I got only the first subheading not all of them)

```
import scrapy

class WikipediaTocSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wikipedia_toc'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)']

    def parse(self, response):
        for toc in response.css('.toclevel-1'):
            yield {
                'heading': toc.css('span.toctext::text').get(),
                'sub_headings': '\n'.join(toc.css('li.toclevel-2 a span.toctext::text').getall())
            }
```

I run this code from powershell like that
`scrapy runspider wikipedia_toc.py -o output.csv`

How can I remove the empty lists?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CSV is not quite suitable for exporting nested values. It's way more handy to use json in this case.
Otherwise, if you do really need to use CSV you'll have to write custom csv exporter for your items.
Take a closer look here: [How to create custom Scrapy Item Exporter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290876/how-to-create-custom-scrapy-item-exporter)

---

To avoid exporting empty lists just add a condition.

```
import scrapy

class WikipediaTocSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wikipedia_toc'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)']

    def parse(self, response):
        for toc in response.css('.toclevel-1'):
            item = {}
            item['heading'] = toc.css('span.toctext::text').get()
            sub_headings = toc.css('li.toclevel-2 a span.toctext::text').getall()
            if sub_headings:
                 item['sub_headings'] = sub_headings
            yield item
```

Comment: I tried to export as JSON but didn't get the required output too ..How can this be exported to JSON in proper way?

Comment: I think using this line like that is OK `'sub_headings': toc.css('li.toclevel-2 a span.toctext::text').getall()`. But how can I avoid the empty lists? An attached snapshot in the question ..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you post the whole code as I am confused..? Forgive me as I am a newbie at python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried but I got one column only in the CSV output. The second column is supposed to be for the subheadings.